# Can I get all perks?

Tags: fallout-4

I know there is no level cap in this game. Does it follow that you can obtain all of the perks, or does it stop at some point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are able to get every perk in the game. However, you will need to reach around level 310 to do so.

Comment: Well that's cool to know then

Comment: Is 310 right? Everywhere else I've seen a number for it, it's been below 300. Nukapedia says you can have all perks and (at least) 10 in every SPECIAL by level 270. http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Level#Fallout_4

Comment: @Iszi I said around 310; I don't know the exact number